# Send multiple oracle tables into single kafka topic

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-topic

I'm using JDBC source connector to transfer data from Oracle to Kafka topic. I want to transfer 10 different  oracle tables to same kafka topic using JDBC source connector with table name mentioned somewhere in message(e.g: header) . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> with table name mentioned somewhere in message

You can use an [ExtractTopic transform](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html) to read the topic name from a column in the tables

Otherwise, if that data isn't in the table, you can use the [InsertField transform](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html) with `static.value` before the extract one to force the topic name to be the same

Note: If you use Avro or other record-type with schemas, and your tables do not have the same schema (column names and types), then you should expect all but the first producer to fail, becuase the schemas would be incompatible